# How to make button same height?

Tags: html, css

How to make the two button that are side by side the same height? [image]

As you can see from the image, the button doesn't have the same height.

```
<div class="register-btn"><span class="register"><a href="http://#" target="_blank">Register Now</a></span><a href="http://#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right arrow-right"></i></a></div>

    .register-btn {
    margin-top: 125px;
    background-color: #23342c;
    float: right;
}

.register {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #2d4137;
    color: #fff;
}

.arrow-right {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #23342c;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend the css property `height`.

Comment: I tried but it's not working for some reason...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can achive with add `display: inline-flex;` to the container of the buttons (in this case is `register-btn`.

```css
.register-btn {
    margin-top: 125px;
    background-color: #23342c;
    float: right;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.register {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #2d4137;
    color: #fff;
}

.arrow-right {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #23342c;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<div class="register-btn"><span class="register"><a href="http://#" target="_blank">Register Now</a></span><a href="http://#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right arrow-right"></i></a></div>
```

2. You can add class `button` to button you want to line up. and add to your css

```css
.register-btn {
    margin-top: 125px;
    background-color: #23342c;
    float: right;
}

.register {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #2d4137;
    color: #fff;
}

.arrow-right {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #23342c;
    color: #fff;
}
.button {
  height: 50px; /* 50px just an example. You can change it by your own */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<div class="button register-btn"><span class="register"><a href="http://#" target="_blank">Register Now</a></span><a href="http://#" class="button" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right arrow-right"></i></a></div>
```

Comment: thanks, the first method seems working for me, but the problem now is the arrow is not vertical align to the button. As for the second method, I tried but I'm not sure why it's not working .

Comment: But when you run in code snippet it's working, right? Maybe you have an external CSS that collide with your CSS right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox CSS:

```
.register-btn {
    /* margin-top: 125px; */
    background-color: #23342c;
    /* float: right; */
    display: inline-flex;
}
```